# Android Get Facebook Wall Posts?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the facebook wall feeds and using this Graph API

```
1. me?fields=posts
2. ?fields=feed
```

but both APIs are returning the same data, which is my post which I have posted earlier.

Kindly advise me how I can get the other feeds which are showing on my feed section when I log in to facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get access to the feed, you can only get access to the posts of the user itself and posts made by his friends on his wall. This has been changed some years ago.